# Opening Word-document (.doc) using C# causes COMException due to File Block Settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, com-interop

I'm trying to open a really old (binary) Word-file using C#/.NET and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Whenever I try to open this file using the snippet below, it fails with a COMException telling me that *"You are attempting to open a file type that is blocked by your File Block settings in the Trust Center."*

This also used to happen when opening the same file in MS Word, but after adjusting the settings found in the Trust Center this now works just fine. However, I still cannot open the file using C#. Does anyone know if VS2010 caches these settings, or use its own settings somewhere? I have also tried to create a new project (after fixing the settings in Word) with the same snippet to see if that helped, but it did not.

```
Word.Application app;

string file = "<filename>";

app = new Word.Application();

try
{
    app.Documents.Open(file);
}
catch (COMException e)
{
    string s = e.Message;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, do you get this if you run the console application as the administrator?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: This is the "Mark of the web". See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx. It's more complicated than that. The change can be made via interop, using the `PersistentZoneIdentifier` coclass. (I only know this because Raymond Chen had a full writeup on this only yesterday.)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/04/10463035.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented with an [*alternate data stream*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29), supported by the NTFS file system.  You access such a stream with the `filename:stream` syntax.  The stream name that stores the info for the file blocking feature is `Zone.Identifier:$DATA`.  It is written by whatever program copied the file, usually a browser.

You can see them with the DIR /R option.  The [SysInternals' Streams utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) permits listing and deleting them.  A silly way to get rid of it is copying it to a file system that doesn't support alternate data streams, like a .zip archive or a flash drive and copying it back.

You can look at the content of the stream or edit it with a command like `notepad filename:zone.identifier`, you'll see this:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

The ZoneId value identifies the origin of the file.  Values are -1=unspecified, 0=local machine, 1=intranet, 2=trusted, 3=internet, 4=untrusted.  What notepad can do is however not possible in .NET, it explicitly forbids using the `:` character in file names. The intention is for a human to deal with this, explicitly overriding the file blocking feature.  Right-click the file in Explorer, Properties and click the Unblock button.  That deletes the stream.  Note the Powershell cmdlets mentioned in the first link.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. The change can be made via interop, using the `PersistentZoneIdentifier` coclass. (I only know this because Raymond Chen had a full writeup on this only yesterday.)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/04/10463035.aspx