# Block windows file

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

There can be "This file came from another computer and might be blocked" message in file properties.
Is there a way to block back file in windows 7?
I need this for program testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to recreate the [alternate data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788330/opening-word-document-doc-using-c-sharp-causes-comexception-due-to-file-block/19791116#19791116) for the file.  The easiest way to do this is by using Notepad.  Run cmd.exe and navigate to the directory that contains the file.  I'll use test.txt as an example, type this command:

```
  Notepad "test.txt:Zone.Identifier"
```

Double quotes required.  Notepad prompts you to create a new file, click Yes.  Paste or write this:

```
  [ZoneTransfer]
  ZoneId=3
```

Press Ctrl+S to save.